# Dot Product of Tensors with Different Shapes in PyTorch

Tags: matrix-multiplication, pytorch, tensor

```python
p=torch.randn(2,3)
q=torch.randn(3,4,5)
```

I want to perform dot product, to obtain a result of shape `(2,4,5)`.

How can this be done with PyTorch?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then **[EDIT]** your question and add the missing information.

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions for multi-dimensional matrix multiplications:

- Use [`Tensor.reshape()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.reshape) to get 2-D tensors and use [`torch.mm()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.mm);
- Use directly [`torch.einsum()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.einsum).

Demonstration:

```python
import torch

p=torch.randn(2,3)
q=torch.randn(3,4,5)

# Solution 1: Reshaping to use 2-dimensional torch.mm()
res1 = torch.mm(p, q.resize(3, 4 * 5)).resize_(2, 4, 5)
print(res1.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 4, 5])

# Solution 2: Using explicit torch.einsum()
res2 = torch.einsum("ab,bcd->acd", (p, q))
print(res2.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 4, 5])

# Checking if results are equal:
print((res1 == res2).all())
# tensor(1, dtype=torch.uint8)
```